# Django [WinError 10053] when loading up server

Tags: django, windows, python-3.9

Whenever I start up my Django server i get the errors shown below. The weird thing is that sometimes the [WinError 10053] doesn't show up and I can develop normally but when it does show up the project seems to malfunction and .css and .js files also don't get loaded.

I have already looked into other stackoverflow questions that seemed related such as setting the correct code page to use with postgres or the python bug mentioned here https://bugs.python.org/issue27682. But I'm using python 3.9 so that bug should be fixed.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The project works just fine on the computers of some other people and everything that we compared seemed the same (settings, pycharm configuration,...).

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59986)
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55047)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
----------------------------------------
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64741)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59454)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "D:\Documents - data drive\StepDB\gitlab\site\Site\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "D:\DataDownloads\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: As an aside, why is your Python apparently installed into "D:/DataDownloads"?

Comment: I have an ssd and hdd disk, the DataDownloads is on the hdd disk to be able to put my program files there so I don't clutter the ssd which has limited space because I'm also running a dual boot

Comment: But... why not a folder whose name would refer to Python? You'll just confuse yourself if you're working with a `D:/DataDownloads/python.exe`...

Comment: You're right, I have reinstalled it into `D:/DataDownloads/python`